# Setting import to get list of values “constraint” for field, as described in INTERLIS Modell, into FileGDB, using Ili2db (ili2fgdb)?

Tags: file-geodatabase, import, interlis

I’m trying to import an **INTERLIS 2** Dataset (Modell (**ili**) and Data (**xtf**)) in a **FileGDB** with the script **ili2fgdb**. The goal is to make some edit in the Datas in ArcMap and then export them back in INTERLIS. To avoid errors by the export I’d like to have all the “constraints” described in the INTERLIS Modell in my Geodatabse to prevent any non-compliant values from being entered in a field.

I’m struggling with the attribute with a defined list of values / classifications (“Aufzähltypen”):

When there is a constraint describing a limited list of possible values for a field (in DOMAIN) in the INTERLIS MODELL, I want to have a dropdown list with those values when I edit that field in ArcMap.

Does someone know which setting I need in my import to get those values as “Coded Values” in the “Domains” settings of my Layer in the Geodatabase (in order to have dropdown lists for the concerned fields)?

(I’ve managed to import those lists of values as “Lookup-Tables” with options like --createEnumTabs, but it doesn’t set constraints on the fields in the tables that are supposed to be limited by one of those lists of values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ili2fgdb 3.x, 4.0 exists no option to create coded domains. A workaround might be: import the enumeration values with  --createEnumTabs or --createSingleEnumTab and create the coded domains with ArcGIS tools.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to GIS.SE, interesting question!

This is a known issue in ili2db, see [createEnumTabs with createFk should create FKs to enum tabs](https://github.com/claeis/ili2db/issues/19) which has been already solved for [ili2db v4.0](https://github.com/claeis/ili2db/milestone/1?closed=1), to arrive in the next couple of months.

However, there is a solution ready to use with ili2db v3.x. It's a QGIS plugin called `QGIS Model Baker` and it creates QGIS layers with forms, widgets and relations from Interlis models. I contribute to such project and we have incorporated our own domain-class parser, so that from an ili model we create the  relation domain-class in QGIS to make data capture/edition much easier. See this demo:

[image]

Right now you could use either PostgreSQL/PostGIS or GeoPackage databases. SQL Server support is coming.

Let me know if you have further questions in this regard.